# blinking and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm writing a game for Free Code Camp and i need to blink a count severale times.

This is the solution i found but it looks ugly:

```
function blinkTheCount(symbol) {

    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = '';

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = symbol;
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = '';
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = symbol;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = '';
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = symbol;
                    }, 200);
                }, 200);
            }, 200);
        }, 200);
    }, 200);

}
```

Could you please give me some help to write it in a more fashionable way?

I tried with for loop but i get into a page hang.

Tank you very much.

Comment: Check out [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). It's a lot like `setTimeout` but repeats itself over and over again.

Comment: if innerHTML length === 0 than text = blah, else text is "" with interval

Comment: Holy s... Yes, check setInterval, please.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to everyone, now it's:

```
function blinkTheCount(symbol) {

    var count = 0;
    var blinkIt = setInterval(function () {
        if (count++ === 5) {
            clearInterval(blinkIt);
        }
        if (document.getElementById('count').innerHTML !== symbol) {
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = symbol;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }, 200);

}
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is probably what you would want to use in this case.

If you don't need to blank out the content of the container, perhaps try swapping between display: block and display: none for the same element. Just check the display status of the container each time and update accordingly.

```js
var count = document.getElementById('count');

setInterval(function() {
  count.style.display = count.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="count">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use `setTimeout` here instead of `setInterval`, not because it's the best option, but just to show the OP how he can control the number of blinks with `setInterval`:

```
var max = 10, i = 0;
var myvalues = ["test", "TEST"];
(function loop(){
   if(i++ > max) return;
   var index = i%2;
   setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = myvalues[index];
       loop();
   }, 200)
}());
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/joypdg6g/